# Reorganize the content of a vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

I would like to reorganize the contents of a vector to start with this for example:

```
// 'v' is the vector

v[0]: "name: "
v[1]: &
v[2]: "James"
v[3]: &
v[4]: 10
v[5]: &
v[6]: "last name: "
v[7]: &
v[8]: "Smith"
```

and get to this:

```
v[0]: "name: " & "James" & 10 & "last name: " & "Smith"
```

This example is very basic.

I tried something like that:

```
std::vector<std::string> organize(std::vector<std::string> tokens) {
        using namespace std;
        vector<string> ret;
        string tmp;
        // The IsString function checks whether a string is enclosed in quotation marks.
        // The s_remove_space function removes spaces from a character string.
        for (string str : tokens) {
            if (IsString(str) || str == tokens[tokens.size() - 1]) {
                ret.push_back(tmp);
                ret.push_back(str);
                tmp.clear();
            }
            else if (s_remove_space(str) != "")
                tmp += str;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

The output is the same as the input, if we take my example from above.
Besides, my way of doing things seems pretty brutal. I guess it's pretty simple to implement with a RegEx system, but I can't / don't want to use them.

Debugging VC++ step-by-step on my project doesn't help me solve the problem. This one seems to me to be very simple to solve...

In my opinion, the mistake is silly, but I've been looking for it for quite some time.

Comment: Why in your example you are not removing spaces, but in your code you are calling `s_remove_space`?

Comment: What is `&`? Your `vector<string>` can only hold strings, not `&`s. Do you mean `"&"` and `v[0]: "name: " & "James" & 10 & "last name: " & "Smith"` should actually be `v[0]: "name: & James & 10 & last name:  & Smith"`?

Comment: *Debugging VC++ step-by-step on my project doesn't help me solve the problem.* -- I don't understand that statement.  You wrote the code with a plan in mind (or on paper), you should be able to step through your program to see where the program diverges from your plan.  You should also have posted a [mcve], as the last comment is correct in that we don't know actually what is in that vector due to the pseudo-code.

Comment: Please provide some test code for your example, so we can understand better.

Comment: @nwp: &' is also a string. I didn't put quotation marks on it so I wouldn't "weigh it down", and have a clearer vision

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Precisely, the plan and debogage gives the same results, but the exit is unexpected. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: @AVN -- If you have [boost](http://www.boost.org/) available, you could do something like [this](https://www.ideone.com/js1Sra) using `algorithm::join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplicity is a virtue, don't overcomplicate stuff.

Here is a naive example, where you just iterate over every token, and you append it to the first string of the vector. Special cases are first and last tokens, where you should append just a whitespace, and just the token, respectively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v = {"\"name: \"", "&", "\"James: \"", "&", "10", "&", "\"last name: \"", "&", "\"Smith\""};
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        if(i == 0)
            v[0] += " ";
        else if(i == v.size() - 1)
            v[0] += v[i];
        else
            v[0] += v[i] + " ";
    }
    cout << "v[0]: " << v[0] << endl;
}
```

Output:

> v[0]: "name: " & "James: " & 10 & "last name: " & "Smith"

Comment: Indeed, it is very simple! Thank you very much, you gave me other ideas for improving my program.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `std::stringstream` is more useful to gather a resulting string.

Also if you don't need the positioning, a range `for` can be used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>

std::vector< std::string >& organize( std::vector< std::string >& v )
{
    std::stringstream result;
    //bool is_first = true;
    //char seperator = ' ';

    for ( const auto& str : v )
    {
        //if (is_first)
        //    is_first = false;
        //else
        //    result << seperator;

        result << str;
    }

    v[ 0 ] = result.str();

    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::string > v = {
          "\"name: \"", "&", "\"James: \"", "&", "10", "&", "\"last name: \"", "&", "\"Smith\""};

    organize( v );

    std::cout << "v[0]: " << v[ 0 ] << std::endl;
}
```